# Django: Making queries the efficient way

Tags: django

Would you consider this the right/efficient way to make queries?

```
discount_code_get = request.GET.get('discount')
    discount_code = Discount.objects.filter(code=discount_code_get)
    discount_code_exists = discount_code.exists()
    if discount_code_exists:
        print(discount_code.first().value)
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#exists):

> Additionally, if a some_queryset has not yet been evaluated, but you
>   know that it will be at some point, then using some_queryset.exists()
>   will do more overall work

You can simple use `first()` to get required object. Since `first` returns None if object does not exist you can do something like this:

```
discount_code = Discount.objects.filter(code=discount_code_get).first()
if discount_code:
    print(discount_code)
```

Answer (score 1):

You here perform two queries: an `EXISTS` and a fetch. You can merge it into one:

```
discount_code_get = request.GET.get('discount')
discount_code= Discount.objects.filter(code=discount_code_get).first()
if discount_code is not None:
    return discount_code.value
```

This works since `.first()` returns `None` if it can not find such database row.

Or even more efficient (given `value` is non-NULLable):

```
# In case value is non-NULLable

discount_code_get = request.GET.get('discount')
discount_value = Discount.objects.values_list(
    'value', flat=True
).filter(code=discount_code_get).first()
if discount_value is not None:
    return discount_value
```

In case the `code` is a `unique` field, it is more idiomatic to use a `try`-`except` here:

```
# in case code is unique

discount_code_get = request.GET.get('discount')
try:
    discount_value = Discount.objects.values_list(
        'value', flat=True
    ).get(code=discount_code_get)
except Discount.DoesNotExist:
    pass
else:
    print(discount_value)
```

Using `.values_list(..)` will reduce the number of *columns* that are fetched (and deserialized). Although that is typically not a huge boost, it can be significant if the number of columns is large, or the data stored in it is large, since then we save on deserializing attributes, that are never used later in the process.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer Willem!